# Memory leak when creating/accessing nodes in n-ary tree

Tags: c++, struct, memory-leaks, constructor, tree

I'm getting memory leaks from the following code:

```
struct Node {
    Node *children[20];
    int value;

    Node();
    ~Node();
};

Node::Node() {
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++) {
        children[i] = NULL;
    }
}

void Node::insert(int x) {
    Node *n = this;
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++) {
        if(n->children[i] == NULL) {
            n->children[i] = new Node();
            n->children[i]->value = x;
        }
        n = n->children[i];
    }
}
```

Checking with Valgrind, apparently I'm getting a leak from this line:

```
n->children[i] = new Node();
```

Is this a wrong way to use the constructor?
Or is the Valgrind check misleading?

Valgrind Error message:

```
505 (448 direct, 57 indirect) bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 3
  at 0x4C2B1C7: operator new(unsigned long)
  by 0x401A4F: Node::insert
  by 0x4015FA: main

LEAK SUMMARY:
  definitely lost: 448 bytes in 2 blocks
  indirectly lost: 57 bytes in 2 blocks
    possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
  still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
       suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

The Destructor I have:

```
Node::~Node() {
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++) {
        delete children[i];
        children[i] = NULL;
    }
}
```

In main:

```
int main() {
    Node *n = new Node();

    .
    .
    .

    delete n;
    n = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you share the valgrind message.

Comment: @AxelBorja I've added the error message to the question.

Comment: I strongly suspect that `insert` has a lot more issues. For instance, the loop looks at the first child, the second child of the first child, the third child of the second child of the first child, etcetera. If these don't exist, they're _all_ created. This means it creates a subtree of depth 20!

Comment: I am also agree with @MSalters, something is strange in your Node::insert(int) method.

Comment: Ironically, the overactive insert helped find the memory leak, and i dont see the code for the destructor

Comment: @MSalters What if I do need all 20 nodes? The purpose might look unclear because I simplified the code, but would that cause a memory leak?

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum Sorry, I forgot to add the destructor code to the question.

Comment: I just ran the above code with both less than and greater than 20 insertions and it doesn't leak... Is there anything else you've omitted which might be pertinent?

Comment: I am agree with @CharlieScott-Skinner, problem probably come from another part of your code. If there is any other method which replace pointers in children array, you have to delete the previous pointer before replacing it, like I suggest you in my answer.

Comment: In addition this code can only ever insert once and it writes that same insert 20 times in progressively deeper children. Then no other inserts are stored. The memory footprint of Node is identical for 1 insert and 1000 inserts.

Comment: While a minimum of code is appreciated, and the allocation is in insert, you need to show any other function that modifies `Node`, do you call remove/erase?

Comment: Your destructor looks okay, would you please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), including the main function?

Answer (score 1):

You are not deleting the children. As answered by Axel, you should add a delete in your destructor. Or better, use an array of unique_ptr, that will take care of destroying the nodes when they get out of scope.

Comment: A vector of `unique_ptr` might be even more appropriate. It's quite unclear whether you always need 20 nodes.

Comment: @MSalters I actually need all 20 nodes; it might look unclear because I simplified it to ask as a question.

Comment: Agree with you, MSalters. Choice, I guess you are building a tree, here, so it will not be infinite and at one point, you will get nodes with no children, but they will take the same amount of memory as those that have 20 children.

Answer (score 0):

You never delete children pointers.

You should delete each allocated pointer of children array in the Node class destructor.

Like that :

```
Node::~Node()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        delete children[i];
    }
}
```

Moreover, if there is any other method which replace pointers in children array, you have to delete the previous pointer before replacing it, like that:

```
...
delete n->children[i];
n->children[i] = new Node();
...
```

or

```
...
delete n->children[i];
n->children[i] = p;  // where p is a pointer of Node
...
```

For information, you have to call *delete* to destroy and deallocate each object you construct on the heap (using *new*).

You could also use smartpointer to avoid to manage children members destruction.

Comment: I actually do have a destructor; I forgot to add it to the question. I have `Node *n = new Node();` in main, then I call `delete t;`, then `t = NULL;` before `return 0;`.

Comment: Manual `delete`s are almost always the wrong thing to do, use smart pointers instead.

Comment: @ArneMertz I'm working on an assignment, and I'm restricted from the use of smart pointers/`unique_ptr`s.

Comment: I proposed you a solution and an explanation to your problem. I am also agree with @ArneMertz and as I suggest you, "You could use smartpointer to avoid to manage children members destruction".

Comment: If you have a destructor as mentionned, the problem is probably due to another method which replace a pointer of children array without deleting the previous one. Do you have any other call of n->children[i] = new Node()  or stuff like that in your code?

Comment: @Choice That restriction is pretty nonsensical, but so are many assignments. Consider to write youself a little RAII-class, a "unique_ptr light" of sorts. Would be a good excercise to deal with memory management as well as a good design decision to separate the concerns of the node and the memory management.

Comment: Have you try to delete your pointer before replacing it (as suggested) ?

Answer (score 0):

I see one new, but no delete's, nor smart pointers. That means you allocate memory without freeing it accordingly. (At least you did not show us the destructor of `Node` where that should be done.)

Apart from that there are several flaws in your code:

- Your use of n looks suspicious and it is not clear if what it does is the right thing or simply a bug. You may want to at least clarify that by a comment or better by using additional functions and meaningful names.
- You don't stop once you have found a NULL pointer and flood the whole array with new Nodes, meaning you can successfully insert exaclty once
- You default-construct a node and assign it a value immediately - probably you should write a corresponding constructor.

Use smart pointers to allocate your memory:

```
struct Node {
    unique_ptr<Node> children[20]; //consider switching to std::array
    int value;

    // no destructor needed, because unique_ptr takes care of itself    
    Node (int newValue);
    void insert(int valueToInsert);
};


void Node::insert(int valueToInsert) {
    auto freeSpot = //find the point where you want to insert the new node
    if ( /*freeSpot is a valid location*/ )
        *freeSpot = make_unique<Node>(x);
}  

Node::Node(int newValue) 
  : value(newValue)
{}
```

That would be a first refactoring you could do

Comment: He uses `n` to descend into the new node.  The reason why is unclear. His base index 0 points to a node, where its index 1 points to a node where its index 2 ...  he only ever uses those 20 nodes the first time, after that insert does nothing

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum thanks for the hint. I am pretty sure what it does is not what he wants it to do, but I edited my answer to leave that issue open.

Comment: He added his destuctor,  it looks fine